# I have simple text file with more than 100k lines and I want to delete the lines which does not contain double quotation in notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

I have simple text file with more than 100k lines and I want to delete the lines which does not contain double quotation in notepad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this approach:

- Open *Mark* dialog
- Check *Bookmark line* check box
- Type `"` into the Search field, and click *Mark all*

[image]

- In *Search* -> *Bookmark*, select *Remove Unmarked Lines*

Result:

[image]